# Unable to analyse dictionary validate expression for field Drawing?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I got "Unable to analyse dictionary validate expression for field Drawing. "this error when compling below program how to resolve this?

```
/*Sample Item master Maintenance Program*/                                      
/* DISPLAY TITLE */   
{us/mf/mfdtitle.i "3+ "}                                  
form
    pt_part colon 25
    with frame a side-labels width 80.
/* SET EXTERNAL LABELS */
setFrameLabels(frame a:handle).

form
   "Enter the Value of" pt__qad13 colon 30 skip(1)
   "Enter the Value of" pt_draw   colon 30 skip(1)
   "Enter the Value of" pt_group  colon 30
    with frame b side-labels width 80.
setFrameLabels(frame b:handle).
view frame a.                                                                   
repeat with frame a:                                                            
   prompt-for pt_part                                                           
    editing:                                                                  
   /* FIND NEXT/PREVIOUS RECORD */                                     
     {us/mf/mfnp.i pt_mstr pt_part "pt_mstr.pt_domain = global_domain and pt_part" pt_part pt_part pt_part }                            
     if recno <> ? then                                                        
          do:                                                                   
           display pt_part.  
          end.
    end.
        find pt_mstr exclusive-lock where pt_domain = global_domain and pt_part = input pt_part .
               disp pt__qad13 pt_draw pt_group with frame b.
               update pt__qad13 pt_draw pt_group with frame b.

end.
```

Comment: check the dictionary validation expression for field: pt_draw

Comment: ade jones' answer is correct, but since somebody is demanding clarification: in Progress, 4GL code is stored in the dictionary and compiled into your code. It's kind of a cross between SQL stored procedures and C include files. It seems this code, which is not visible in the above code sample, has a syntax error in it. To correct this, you need to use the Progress Data Dictionary application inspect the value of the dictionary validation expression. You could also query it directly, in the _field table. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: the built in database validation is outdated. If possible don't use it and best of all: even remove it if you can!

You need to check your dictionary validation. Go to the Data Dictionary, select the database and field (pt_draw). 
Here's an example:
[image: Data Dictionary]

Double click the field or choose "Field Properties" this will open the Field properties dialog where you should select Validation:

[image: Field Properties dialogue]

In the field validation you can enter some code that needs to validate to TRUE for the field to be updated. You can also enter a message that appears if you fail:

[image: Testfield validation]

You should be aware that you're here without any help. You can enter almost anything and there's no syntax check. Here's my validation for testfield2:

[image: Testfield2 validation]

If I try to update testfield and don't enter "TEST 1" or "TEST 2" I get an error:

[image]

Simple program:

```
CREATE testtable.
UPDATE testfield.
```

Now adding my (crippled) testfield 2 won't even compile:

```
CREATE testtable.
UPDATE testfield testfield2.
```

[image: Error message]

(My installation is Swedish but this basically means:

- Unknown field or variable: asdasdasdasdasd
- Cannot analyze field validation in the dictionary for testfield2

**Fixing this**

If you for some reason or another can't (or wont) remove your crippled validation you can let the ABL take care of it for you:

Add a validation option

```
CREATE testtable.
UPDATE testfield testfield2 VALIDATE(TRUE, "").
```

> VALIDATE(logical expression, message if not TRUE)

This will override whatever you have in the dictionary. You could of course write something more valid than my example above:

```
CREATE testtable.
UPDATE testfield testfield2 VALIDATE(TRIM(testtable.testfield2) <> "", "Field cannot be blank").
```

Comment: +1 for -- don't use validation!  the capability made a good demo in 1985.  as a feature it is not something that should be used in 2016